# Pull user input from multiple textboxes and pass as list back to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have a view made of multiple partial views, each of those partials creating user input fields for data that will eventually be stored in multiple tables: one for each partial view.

I can write single row data back to the database just fine. Below, the .Add(primary) works just fine because there is always only a single first and last name for the primary table.

However, sometimes there are multiple phone numbers for a given postback. I need to load each of those up into a phone table list and then pull them back out in the Create method, right? Here's the current Create method of my controller.

```
    public ActionResult Create(PrimaryTable newprimary, List<PhoneTable> newphone)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {


            db.PrimaryTables.Add(newprimary);


            foreach (var phone in newphone)
            {
                phone.CareGiverID = newCareGiverID;
                db.tblPhones.Add(phone);
                db.tblPhones.Last().CareGiverID = newCareGiverID;
            }


            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

And my current phone partial view.

```
@model IList<FFCNMaintenance.Models.PhoneTable>



<div>
<label class="label-fixed-width">Phone:</label>
@Html.TextBox("Phone1", null, new { style = "width: 600px" })
<br />
<label class="label-fixed-width">Phone:</label>
@Html.TextBox("Phone2", null, new { style = "width: 600px" })
<br />



</div>
```

But, as is probably obvious, simply naming them Phone1 and Phone2 does not auto load them up into a List of phone table types.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you will have access to `Phone1`, `Phone2`, etc in the `Request.Params` object.  `Request.Params` is a combination of all fields (query string, form fields, server variables, cookies, etc).

If you want the fields to map automatically from the View to the parameters in your controller methods (i.e. the `List<PhoneTable>`) you can implement your own customer `ModelBinder`.

Here's a quick (untested) example to give you an idea of how a custom model binder might work.

```
public class PhoneModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // If not the type that this binder wants, return null.
        if (!typeof(List<PhoneTable>).IsAssignableFrom(bindingContext.ModelType))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var phoneTable = new List<PhoneTable>();

        int i = 1;

        while (true)
        {
            var phoneField = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Phone" + i.ToString());

            if (phoneField != null)
            {
                phoneTable.Add(new PhoneTable() { Number = phoneField.AttemptedValue });
                i++;
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        return phoneTable;
    }
}
```

To register this binder you would need to add it to the collection of model binders, or use a custom model binder provider to determine which model binder to use.  Here's how to simply add it to the collection of model binders.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(List<PhoneTable>), new PhoneModelBinder());
```

Comment: Awesome. Will implement later today and test. Thanks, @PeteGO, for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP works as it does. It knows nothing about lists or C#. You'll have to bind parameters to your list on the server side.